# Does Higher order polymorphism require strict order of arguments?

Tags: haskell, syntax, higher-kinded-types

Reading [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/for-a-few-monads-more#writer), I stumbled upon this piece of code:

```
newtype Writer w a = Writer { runWriter :: (a, w) }

instance (Monoid w) => Monad (Writer w) where  
  return x = Writer (x, mempty)  
  (Writer (x,v)) >>= f = let (Writer (y, v')) = f x in Writer (y, v `mappend` v')
```

While trying to understand what the heck is `Writer w` in the first line, I discovered this not being a full type, but a sort of type constructor with 1 argument, like `Maybe` for `Maybe String`

Looks great, but what if the initial type if `Writer'` is defined with swapped type arguments, like this:

```
newtype Writer' a w = Writer' { runWriter :: (a, w) }
```

**Is it possible to implement Monad instance now?** Something like this, but what could actually be compiled:

```
instance (Monoid w) => Monad (\* -> Writer' * monoid) where
```

The idea of `\* -> Writer' * monoid` is the same as `Writer w` :
A type constructor with one type argument missing -- this time first one.

Comment: You define `Writer` for the explicit purpose of having a `Monad` instance. There's no point of defining it with swapped arguments. And you cannot write such type-level functions if you want decidable type checking.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not possible in Haskell, what you'd need is a type-level lambda function, which does not exist.

There are type synonyms which you can use to define reorderings of type variables:

```hs
type Writer'' a w = Writer' a w
```

but you can not give class instances for partially applied type synonyms (even with the `TypeSynonymInstances` extension).

I wrote my MSc thesis about the subject of how type-level lambdas can be added to GHC: https://xnyhps.nl/~thijs/share/paper.pdf to be used in type-class instances without sacrificing type inference.

Comment: So, thats's what lambda types in scala are for!.. Right?

Comment: Indeed, there's an example in the Related Work on how that works in Scala. The trade-off for Scala is that you almost always need to give type annotations when using type classes.

Answer (score 5):

What you are seeing here is a parochial design choice of Haskell.  It makes perfect sense, conceptually speaking, to say that your `Writer'` type is a functor if you "leave out" its first parameter.  And a programming language syntax could be invented to allow such declarations.

The Haskell community hasn't done so, because what they have is relatively simple and it works well enough.  This isn't to say that alternative designs aren't possible, but to be adopted such a design would have to:

1. Be no more complex to use in practice than what we already have;
2. Offer functionality or advantage that would be worth the switch.

This generalizes to many other ways that the Haskell community uses types; often the choice to represent something as a type distinction is tied to some artifact of the language's design.  Many monad transformers are good examples, like `MaybeT`:

```
newtype MaybeT m a = MaybeT { runMaybeT :: m (Maybe a) }

instance Functor m => Functor (MaybeT m) where ...
instance Applicative m => Applicative (MaybeT m) where ...
instance Monad m => Monad (MaybeT m) where ...
instance MonadTrans MaybeT where ...
```

Since it's a `newtype`, this means that `MaybeT IO String` is **isomorphic** to `IO (Maybe String)`; you can think of the two types as being two "perspectives" on the same set of values:

1. `IO (Maybe String)` is an `IO` action that produces values of type `Maybe String`;
2. `MaybeT IO String` is a `MaybeT IO` action that produces values of type `String`.

The difference between the perspectives is that they imply different implementations of the `Monad` operations.  In Haskell then this is also tied to the following parochial technical facts:

- In one `String` is the last type parameter (the "values") and in the other `Maybe String` is;
- `IO` and `MaybeT IO` have different instances for the `Monad` class.

But maybe there is a language design where you could say that the type `IO (Maybe a)` can have a monad specific to it, and distinct from the monad for the more general `IO a` type.  That language would incur *some* complexity to make that distinction consistently (e.g., rules to determine which `Monad` instance to by default for `IO (Maybe String)` and rules to allow the programmer to override the default choice).  And I'd wager modestly that the end result would be no less complex than what we do have.  **TL;DR:** Meh.

Comment: What do you mean by "parochial" here?

Comment: Specific to Haskell and its community.   Some of the category theory notation does show a different convention—people talk about things like "the *— × B* functor" where the dash refers to a "hole" in an expression like *A × B*.  Maybe somebody could come up with a language design where you could say `instance Monoid m => Monad (Writer' _ m)` or `instance Monoid m => Monad (\a -> Writer' a m)` or something. The main reason we don't have this in Haskell, I'd contend, is because what we do have works fine!